# What is the difference b/w str_detect with & without "fixed" in pattern?

Tags: r

Here is sample string

```
x<-"My name is XYZ, I'm from ABc, working at PQR"
```

and want to detect "," in the string and using two forms:

```
> str_detect(x,",")
[1] TRUE
> 
> str_detect(x,fixed(","))
[1] TRUE
```

Both returning same result. Then what is the difference b/w these two?

Comment: Guess you are not aware of what a "regular expression" is. See `?regex` to start. Regular expressions are meant to find *patterns* of characters in a string. For instance, you might want to know if a string contains a sequence of numbers  or other patterns. With `fixed = TRUE`, you just want to find an *exact* match of a substring into a string. With `fixed = FALSE` you want to find patterns using the grammar of regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, we may need to use a different example with `regex`.  Here, we are trying to check whether the upper case letter 'R' is at the end (`$`) of the string.  With `fixed` as wrapper, it checks whether we have `R$` as character`and without it, it evaluates`$` as the end of the string as it is a metacharacter.

```
str_detect(x,fixed("R$"))
#[1] FALSE
str_detect(x,"R$")
#[1] TRUE
```

---

The `,` is not a metacharacter and is evaluated as `,` whether we are using with `fixed` or without `fixed`.  In general, if we are specifically looking for finding the literal character, use the `fixed` wrapper and it should be fast as well.

Comment: It seems so much of it. But learnt something with this. Thank you.